c7n-mailer configuration on AWS
I've already added AmazonSQSFullAccess and AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-191 sunnyvalelabs]$ c7n-mailer --config mailer.yml --update-lambda
2024-08-20 17:12:05,524 - custodian-mailer - INFO - Provisioning mailer lambda us-west-2
2024-08-20 17:12:05,653 - custodian.serverless - INFO - Publishing custodian policy lambda function cloud-custodian-mailer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/c7n-mailer", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n_mailer/cli.py", line 257, in main
    deploy.provision(mailer_config, functools.partial(session_factory, mailer_config))
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n_mailer/deploy.py", line 102, in provision
    manager.publish(func)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/mu.py", line 391, in publish
    result, changed, existing = self._create_or_update(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/c7n/mu.py", line 516, in _create_or_update
    result = self.client.create_function(**params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1021, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.


create a new role called CloudCustodianRole of entity type "AWS service" with use case of "lambda". Add the permission of "AmazonSESFullAccess", "AmazonSQSFullAccess" and "AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole"
